# Unified Agents implementaiton

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-devops, devops

I have a single Agent pool having 4 agent machines. I am building my code and it is getting successfully using a single agent out of 4.

Achieve: I want to achieve compilation and testing using Unified Agent Pool.The same pool I want to use for Testing.

I create a Release definition and create an agent phase: Selected the option Execute on Multiple Agents using same pool I used in Build Agent. (Concept is achieving the exact functionality of Unified Agent).

Create the Visual Studio test V2 task and in the Search folder as used $(BuildOutput) . Test Assemblies as : *test*.dll !\obj* and selected RUN TESTS in Parallel on multicore machines.

Output:

Build run successfully and when it automatically trigger the release definition it shows these errors:

First error: `No artifacts are available in the build 47777.`

```
2018-07-16T13:19:38.0507114Z ##[error]Error: Preparing the test sources file failed. Error : Error: No test sources found matching the given filter '*test*.dll,!\obj**'

2018-07-16T13:19:38.0507114Z ##[error]Error: Preparing the test sources file failed. Error : Error: No test sources found matching the given filter '*test*.dll,!\obj**'
```

Question: am I going in right direction for an implementation of Unified Agent using VSTest v.2.

What should i do for resolving these errors and going into right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the key problem:

> No artifacts are available in the build 47777.

Your build is not publishing any artifacts. Your build has to use the `Publish Artifacts` task to publish the build outputs in order to make them available in a release definition.

When artifacts are successfully published to a build, there is an "Artifacts" tab that appears on the build summary that will allow you to browse and validate the build outputs.

Comment: No test sources found matching the given filter '**\*test*.dll,!**\obj\**'    Above error resolved bu this error is still occurring.

Comment: Try `**\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**`.

Comment: @DevOps Is that working with Cece's sugesstion? any update?